# 'PySide2.QtGui' has no attribute 'QRegularExpressionValidator'

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2, qregexp, qregularexpression

I am building a ASCIIValidator with the help of the Qt c++ source code which relies on the QRegularExpression classes instead of their old QRegExp counterparts.
To make an example, please take a look at line 916 of https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/gui/util/qvalidator.cpp

```
class ASCIIValidator(QtGui.QRegularExpressionValidator):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ASCIIValidator, self).__init__()
        self.description = ""
        self.invalidInputMsg = ""

        self.regex = QtCore.QRegularExpression(r"[^\x00-\x7F]")
        self.setRegularExpression(self.regex)
        self.regex.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        
    
    def validate(self, _input: str, pos: int) -> QtGui.QValidator.State:
        if self.regularExpression().pattern().isEmpty():
            return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable
        
        match = self.regularExpression().match(_input, 0, QtCore.QRegularExpression.PartialPreferCompleteMatch)
        if match.hasMatch(): # means that a non-ascii character has been foound
            return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
        else:
            return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable
```

throws the following error:

```
    from util.UValidator import UValidator
  File ".....\UValidator.py", line 38, in <module>
    class ASCIIValidator(QtGui.QRegularExpressionValidator):
AttributeError: module 'PySide2.QtGui' has no attribute 'QRegularExpressionValidator'
```

However, the Qtdocs as well as PySide2 docs list QRegularExpressionValidator as part of QtGui and even recommend using them over the old QRegExp classes.
I'm using lastest python3 with pyside2 installed via pip.
EDIT: using PySide 5.15